# Solving Triple Integral without polar coords.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int_0^1\int_0^2\int_0^3 \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}\ dzdydx$

I don't really care about the limits of this function, so long as the lower are 0 and the upper are not functions of x,y, or z.

How would one integrate this without polar substitution?

I tried a u substitution, but I end with y (or x) in the denominator and when integrating with 0 as a lower bound this approaches infinity.. Is L'Hopital's rule needed here?

Either way, I don't see a way to get a nice answer such as $16\pi$.. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is independent of the technique or substitution you use to solve it.

Comment: I know this, but I still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: How to sove it? Polar coordinates, maybe this is the simplest method available.

Comment: I know how to solve it with polar coordinates. I was wondering how one would go about solving it without Polar coords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have troubles while solving the inner integral with respect to $x$ (or $y$). Assume you want to solve it with respect $x$ so you have $$\int\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dx$$ in which $y$ is supposed to be constant here. For solving it, you can use the [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) by setting $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=t-x$$

Comment: $\ddot\smile$+1

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^1\int_0^2\int_0^3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~dz~dy~dx$

$=\int_0^1\int_0^2\left[z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right]_0^3~dy~dx$

$=\int_0^1\int_0^23\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~dy~dx$

$=\int_0^1\biggl[\dfrac{3y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}+\dfrac{3x^2\ln\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}{2}\biggr]_0^2~dx$ (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_irrational_functions)

$=\int_0^1\dfrac{6\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}dx+\int_0^1\dfrac{3x^2\ln\left(2+\sqrt{x^2+4}\right)}{2}dx-\int_0^1\dfrac{3x^2\ln x}{2}dx$

Can you take it from here?